# How can I write an interface for a nested object if I'm not sure what the keys will be called?

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm attempting to write an interface for the response data of stock prices.

For example, when requesting for the stock prices in a particular date range for Google, I get the following:

```
{
  "daily_prices": {
    "2019-05-10": {
      "open": 1168.84,
      "high": 1176.28,
      "low": 1146.37,
      "close": 1167.64
    },
    "2019-05-13": {
      "open": 1145.24,
      "high": 1151.97,
      "low": 1125.5,
      "close": 1136.59
    },
    "2019-05-14": {
      "open": 1142.32,
      "high": 1144.87,
      "low": 1123.53,
      "close": 1124.86
    },
    "2019-05-15": {
      "open": 1122.55,
      "high": 1178.3,
      "low": 1121.4,
      "close": 1170.8
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to write an interface for this but I don't know how many objects will exist within the `daily_prices` objects. And I don't know what the `property` will either.

I want to do something like this:

```
interface stockPrices {
  daily_prices: {
    SOME_KIND_OF_DATE: {
      open: number,
      high: number,
      low: number,
      close: number
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't know how many of the objects will be within `daily_prices` either.

Any ideas?

Comment: The interface for arbitrary keys is just `{ [key: string]: value }`, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Comment: I didn't realise it was arbitrary keys that I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) for this, i.e. `{ [key: string]: ... }`:

```
interface StockPrices {
  daily_prices: {
    [key: string]: {
      open: number,
      high: number,
      low: number,
      close: number
  } }
}
```

See example of [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPYINYAUrBIDOyA3gLABQyyAJnMADYCeA+gA4HEBcZVNNANrYIzXkTAEQAcwC6vCtQE0M7CCF4gArgFsARtAA0-ZcgAWwaWc26DUY0uWMMAdxv6jJ5QmdEI7uxMAX2QgqjDKKgQMEAk6ODA4XnQsPC4IEgBePiUAInomNk5CDNyFL2RcgCYABgBGAE4AWhqAVia6mrKc00rVdW66uoA2AA4AOlGAFgde3IsrQbqAdmHxqtHZ01znFyWptYBmZa3lXJ8MPyXh5fHhqYqg08raxpb2usPuxTn+kH3WusZhUaPNLGYlq06uMGicQZVdksqoDWs9QRcrrwhoc1q0Go9ntV6s02h0pt94bk-vsquNDlU0ZUFhCsXUplNJnDHAIdq4kYdxq1Dozzr4IEiOaNhgSKkS3qS6q0KdzQdTWVVaa1UZTmUtlhNhZTEerocCVZUMeLWcsapNHsFwgBuIA).

---

### Consider abstracting the nested interface

If you want better readability, you can even abstract the nested interface:

```
interface StockPrice {
  open: number,
  high: number,
  low: number,
  close: number
}

interface StockPrices {
  daily_prices: { [key: string]: StockPrice }
}
```

See example on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPYINYAUrBLIDeAsAFDLIYAOEIAXMiAK4C2ARtADQVUAWwAOb8mrTjz7IANhgDuY9lyi9KyBLIDOERRKgUAvhQqhIsRCnRY8BJJpJSAJnGDSAngH0atiJqbFkAG1sCDcmTTACECEAXSYrHHxCFCNyVIoEDBAI5GcwOHjMRJ97AF4HNQAiZ1dPb2TNSv8pKkqAJgAGAEYATgBaDoBWPq6OpoqqSeRK2npxrq6ANgAOADplgBZVKdbBEXmugHZF1bbl7Z3K2TkDjZOAZkOLqcqNDG0DxcPVxY2W5AMz2mnV6A2GXXu4zIahesxAt0Gpy2-12wn4B0GXVWPSeKOm1wObURgyBrTeHyYC3uJ0GPX%20gP%207W6-SGIw2ULxMzo8MpXQ2bVW9zapOme3RvI2G3WuJhkyu8kJ91Wg3uIteWgghKly0W9KBTNBrK6gw5stacMJAsGJM5YoOhzWqs5BN5bSxyLN03Jmt5hw663pUlSBgA3EA).

---

### Use `Record<T, K>` or a generic helper type

Even better, you can take advantage of the [`Record<>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) (see on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPYINYAUrBLIDeAsAFDLIYAOEIAXMiAK4C2ARtADQVUAWwAOb8mrTjz7IANhgDuY9lyi9KyBLIDOERRKgUAvhQqhIsRCnRY8BJJpJSAJnGDSAngH0atiJqYAlCAQMKEcAHk0wAhAhbjRMHHxCCAA%20Q2NyYJBI5GcwOCYrRJ97AF4HNQAiZ1dPb2TNSqYyNSpKgCYABgBGAE4AWk6AVn7uzqaKqinkStp6Ce7ugDYADgA6FYAWVWm2wREF7oB2JbX2lZ3dytk5Q83TgGYjy%20nKjQxtQ6WjtaXNqSoBheMy6fUGI26DwmLV2MzmIDuQzO2wBU0q%2034hyG3TWvWeqLaN0O7SRQ2BbXenyYiwepyGvVRQNRHR6A2Go020IJcLoCOp3U27TWD3a5JmGLumw2%20NaaKJ-PaDzWQweYreWggxKlKyWjOBLLB7O6Qy5sra8OJQqGZO56OEmP5R3Wqtt8uQi3aOJRZpmlM1js6G0ZUiM5AMAG4gA)):

```
interface StockPrice {
  open: number,
  high: number,
  low: number,
  close: number
}

interface StockPrices {
  daily_prices: Record<string, StockPrice>
}
```

...or declare a generic `Dictionary` interface for that (see on [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgY2HA9gOwIYCcQB4AqAfFALxQDeUA2gNYQgBcUAzsFnGgOYC6T%20UAXwDcAWABQ4jsAhYAZhgTQAysBQIaABXaKK4qFBSQ0TNAFcAtgCMZAGj1QAFnE4OTF61jtj9AGxQB3NytbewQ-Zgggj3EBcUk0aTkFZVV1LUQIZl1vKAATDDgfEAB9MG1MpngkVEwcXBU1TXLCGLixBHRWPIxgDCYGtPKssnJ7ACJ8wpKyjOYxplGc-TGAJgAGAEYATgBaNYBWHY21%20ez9c6gxwwg0U42NgDYADgA6J4AWLwvlpxc7jYA7A8Xisnl9vmM-P5-u9gQBmAHgi5jMIoCL-B4Al4Pd72fQCJGXdbbPaHDZw06Lb6Xa63Jj3d77EGfPHnMa-Bz-fYbF5bRGs5ZQ-4rJn7QnLVHo%20nk4H7Lasgms1abXYHI7vSkCmlGGErF5wlbiy4cmHvN78pZsoXSlZwl77OFGlHhCDCs1PB4KwnKklqjb7TWW5a04V6-ZirXs5yc6UA16OyPWqD3FY8llBy6S12xtZvBX2WJiYRAA):

```
// For bigger projects, this can be stashed away as a generic util/helper type
type Dictionary<T> = { [key: string]: T };

interface StockPrice {
  open: number,
  high: number,
  low: number,
  close: number
}

interface StockPrices {
  daily_prices: Dictionary<StockPrice>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I couldn't even understand the question but you already have an amazing answer. I have been using typescript for over a year now and i didn't actually know they are called indexable :)

Comment: I didn't realise it was arbitrary keys that I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CiBoz Thanks for the kind words.

Comment: @judgejab Glad to be able to help :)